# Ajax Post Data with negative number

Tags: ajax, post, negative-number

i have a problem with Ajax post data with negative number 
i am using this one

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "?page=invresults",  
    data: "Bound=1",  
  });
```

it send data 1 to php without any problem

```
if(isset($_POST['Bound']))
{
echo $_POST['Bound'];
}
```

but when i try to send data with negative number nothing send to php

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "?page=invresults",  
    data: "Bound=-1",  
  });
```

it dont send data to php :S

Answer (score 1):

Send the value as a string like "-1" and on the php side, convert it to an int.